# Quartz Cron expression :Run every 15 days ie twice in a month

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to set the scheduler with a quartz cron expression which will trigger every 15 days ,for example 1st and 15th of every month.The  0 15 10 15 * ? is triggering only on 15th of every
month.

Answer (score 12):

I have tested this and the following expression works fine

```
        "0 0 0 1,15 * ?"
```

the 1,15 statement fires triggers on 1st and 15th of every month at 00:00 hours.
You can change the first three zeroes to fire them at a particular time you want.

the 1st zero -> seconds

the 2nd zero -> minutes

the 3rd zero -> hours

Comment: 1st - min, 2nd - hour, 3rd - dom,4th - mon,5th - dow

Comment: is "quartz" different than standard linux cron (as described by karthik v)?

Answer (score 2):

0 0 1,15 * *
“At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 and 15.”

0 0 1,15 1 *
“At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 and 15 in January.”

0 0 1,15 1 6
“At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 and 15 and on Saturday in January.”

Answer (score 2):

The following also works fine, it executes your command on the 15th and the 30th at 02:00 AM of every month:

```
0 2 */15 * * <yourCommand>
```

Comment: True, but this no longer has a 15 day interval, as OP requested :-)

Comment: It seems like this would skip a run in February.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append 1 with a comma to your expression at 'Day of Month' block.

Rest is fine !

0 15 10 1,15 * ?

This will schedule to run every 1st and 15th day of the month and 10:15 am.