# How To Run Node-Schedule Task Every 15 Days In Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, intervals, schedule

I'm using Node-Schedule package and I'm having some trouble to define the criteria using the * system.
Does anyone know how can I run this task every day 15 and 30 of a month (15 days interval)

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule'); 
var tarefa = schedule.scheduleJob('15-30 * * ', function() {
    console.log("TAREFA");
});
```

One more question, let's say I wanna change this later based on user selected option, how can I get this current task schedule and change this interval later?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0 0 0 1,15 * ?` should work (see  [Quartz Cron expression :Run every 15 days ie twice in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604362/quartz-cron-expression-run-every-15-days-ie-twice-in-a-month)).

To change the schedule, you can call the `rescheduleJob` method with the job's name and the new user-specified schedule.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule')
schedule.scheduleJob('myJob', '0 0 0 1,15 ? *', function() { console.log('hi') } )
schedule.rescheduleJob('myJob', '0 0 0 1,20 ? *')
```

Comment: Just one last question, should I create a new schedule to run in order to check when has user changed schedules?
For example, a main task who controlls smallers tasks?
User goes to config view and changes time option, another task needs to be running to check if tasks were changed
Thank you @snorthway ! Helped a lot!

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your application, but I assume that there's a handler function that gets called any time the user changes a config option. You would put the call to `rescheduleJob` inside that function.